# Cannot resolve import org.dom4j.*

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am working on a servlet/java project in eclipse, and one of the java files contains methods from the dom4j library. However the library import cannot be resolved

```
import org.dom4j.*;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
```

I added dom4j library (`org.dom4j.feature.group`) through eclipse's Install New Software option but import. I noticed that `org.dom4j` is not listed as a jar file in the Referenced Libraries subfolder. What would be the proper way to add this library to the project so that it could be resolved?

Comment: Don't forget to earn your 2 reputation points by clicking the tick on the answer that match your question best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right click on your project
- then click on Configure Build Path
- On the window, click on the button Add external Jars
- Browse to the jar that contain org.dom4j* classes

Comment: That worked, thanks. But just a general question - is there some speciall process for adding libraries to a project from the Install New Software option (other than just straightforward location and installation)?

Comment: "Install Software option" is used for adding plugins to Eclipse itself not to your own programs. If you want some special process for adding libraries i'd suggest you to check out Maven here : http://maven.apache.org/ and its corresponding plugin for Eclipse : http://eclipse.org/m2e/.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the jar yourselves, then just right click on that jar in project explorer and then click -> Configure build path -> Add to build path.

Answer (score 1):

This page help me [add external library in eclipse](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44) and in this page we can download the library [download library](https://dom4j.github.io/)

- Right-click in the project and go to properties
- Select "Java Build Path" on the left, and then the "Libraries" tab. Now, click the "Add External JARS..." button
- Locate and select the "xXx.jar" file you just downloaded, and then click "Open"
- Finally, click "OK" to close the dialog box. You will know that everything went ok if, when you open your project folder, you see an item called "Referenced Libraries", and upon expanding this item, you see the package "xXx.jar" listed.